# How to save one pdf in different places

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfstamper

I create a pdf file using `pdfstamper` and I want to save my pdf in two different files (change the path in the `pdfStamper`)  do I need to create a new `pdfStamper` or is there a way to save in multiple places the same file

// that's my code

```
  PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(rdr, new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Create));
```

Comment: You need to check if `PdfStamper` class has any method to save to different location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly - you need to put the same file in different places, right? It seems to me the most logical thing is to perform all the necessary operations on one pdf-file and then make a copy of it using method `System.IO.File.Copy(path, new_path);`